R: sp::merge does not merge sp-object and df as wanted
I am trying to join a sf-object and a df by a common column name, and have tried sp::merge without succeeding.
Sorry for formatting in advance.
I would like to keep all data from the sf object, including the geometry, and join the data from the df to the matching rows while adding the columns with data from the df.
I've made two sets of small dfs just to illustrate what happens when I run the script and what I'd like the result to be, as the originals have 20+12 columns and are in norwegian.
# Example datasets with identical letters in the fieldnames column
> head(df)
     fieldnames x.df y.df
1             X    6    l
2             Y    7    m
3             B    8    n
4             L    9    o
5             V   10    p

> head(sf)
     fieldnames y.sf geometry
1             X    a        1
2             Y    b        2
3             B    c        3
4             L    d        4
5             V    e        5

The results I am getting now
# When I use the following line of code
sf <- sp::merge(sf, df, by="fieldnames")

> The only output from this is an sf object with all column names but zero rows


#When I use all=TRUE
sf <- sp::merge(sf, df, by="fieldnames", all=TRUE)

      fieldnames y.sf x.df y.df geometry
1              B    c    NA   NA       3
2              B   NA    8    n        NA
3              L    d    NA   NA       4
4              L   NA    9    o        NA
5              V    e    NA   NA       5
6              V   NA    10   p        NA
7              X    a    NA   NA       1
8              X   NA    6    l        NA
9              Y    b    NA   NA       2
10             Y   NA    7    m        NA


> Produces a sf with the wanted columns but the data is not merged per se, the rows from the df are added into the sf, and the sf-data are kept in their original columns, while data from the df is kept in the original df columns. 

I've also tried the following line, which was given as a solution in another thread, but it doesn't work as I get the added error
sf@data = data.frame(sf@data, df[match(sf@data[,fieldnames], df[,fieldnames]),])

#  Error in data.frame(sfs@data, df[match(sf@data[,  : 
#  trying to get slot "data" from an object (class "sf") that is not an S4 object 

> This I didn't understand, tried to look up the message but couldn't find the solution to solving it

This is the result I wanted.
     fieldnames y.sf x.df y.df geometry
1             X    a    6    l        1
2             Y    b    7    m        2
3             B    c    8    n        3
4             L    d    9    o        4
5             V    e   10    p        5

Basically a left_join as far as I've understood how a left_join works, but I've tried that as well with the sf object as the first object to add in columns from the df, and that only produces the sf-data set with empty columns from the df.
Any suggestions to how this can be solved?
